# Transform linear, equally spaced points to a gaussian over the same interval?

Tags: normal-distribution, data-transformation, linear

Suppose I have linearly and equally spaced data points over an interval, e.g. 500 points over the interval 1.5 to 2.3, how would I transform these points so that they are normally distributed over the same interval with a mean of the midpoint of the range and a standard deviation of say a quarter of the range?

I would want to transform the values of the original data to new values that meet the normality requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take each point $X_i$ and transform it as $Y_i = \frac{X_i-1.5}{2.3-1.5}$ so that $Y_i \in [0,1]$. Then create variables $Z_i$ where $Z_i$ is the quantile function for a $N(\frac{2.3-1.5}{2},(\frac{2.3-1.5}{4})^2)$ distribution evaluated at $Y_i$.

In R, that would look something like this:

```
for (i in 1:length(X)){
      Y[i] = (X[i]-1.5)/(2.3-1.5)
      Z[i] = qnorm(Y[i],mean=((2.3-1.5)/2),sd=((2.3-1.5)/4))}
```